# Debugging options unavailable in Eclipse after ADT reinstall

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

In an attempt to fix an apparent problem with Eclipse no longer automatically building my project, I re-installed the Android Developer Toolkit (v15) via Eclipse.

After this, everything seems to be working (breakpoints, etc.), except that the stop button in the debug perspective is always disabled, including the "resume", "suspend", "terminate" and "disconnect" buttons in the toolbar.

[image]

Furthermore, breakpoints aren't acknowledged, and in the popup that appears when I change code while the debug session is in progress, I no longer have a "terminate" option, only "disconnect".

Has anyone else encountered this? I am using a T-Mobile G2 as my device.

EDIT: I have now fully re-installed Eclipse & ADT on a fresh machine and the 'stop' option is still missing. I wonder if this was removed in v15?

Comment: could you please make a comment on your resolution or mark a question as correct?

Comment: I have not solved this problem.  I will try the latest answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved this problem resetting the debug perspective at default: right-click the debug perspective button, select "Reset" and confirm.

After that my "Terminate" button was again enabled.

Comment: Brilliant, I've been suffering with this issue for months now!! Annoyingly, this page didn't come up in the google search, maybe because the title has stop/terminate rather than 'stop or terminate' !! might be worth renaming to catch both words in a search.

Comment: Thanks! I had to also restart Eclipse for the terminate button to return.

Comment: Resetting my perspective didn't resolve this directly, but switching to a different profile and back did. It seems purely an Eclipse issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebooting Eclipse? I was JUST dealing with this same issue until I just restarted it. I figure YOU know this by now, but in case someone else is in my shoes reading this post... :-)

Comment: Yep, I've tried restarting Eclipse.  I haven't gone ahead and done a full re-install, which I presume would fix it; just hoping that it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have an odd variation on this.

After workspace corruption required me to rebuild a new workspace, the terminate button is only active when the Debug pane's FIRST line (my-app-name [Android Application]) is selected.

NOTE: Debugging on Genymotion emulator, not with Eclipse ADT's built-in device emulator.

This never was an issue before; previously it was either automatically selecting that line, or it wasn't requiring it to be selected. Not sure which.

@Gavagai's solution (Reset Debug perspective) doesn't solve it.

So the work-around is to manually select that FIRST line in Debug pane.